# Use of =.. predicate to perform symbolic manipulation of furmulas in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I am learning Prolog for an **universitary** *university* exam using SWI Prolog and I have some doubts about how it work this exercise that use the univ **=..** `=..` predicate to perform symbolic manipulation of **furmulas** *formulas* where a frequent operation is to **substituite** *substitute* some subexpression by another expression.

It is perform defining the following relation:

**substituite(SubTerm, Term, SubTerm1, Term1)**

that it is TRUE if Term1 **rappresent** *represents* Term expression in which all the occurrences of SubTerm are substituited by SubTerm1.

For example if I have:

**substituite(sin(x), 2*(sin(x)), t, F).**

Then: **F = 2*t*f(t)** because all the sin(x) occurrences are substituited by t

This is the solution (founbd on Bratko book) but I am not so sure about my interpretation:

```
% substitute( Subterm, Term, Subterm1, Term1)
% Term1 is Term with all occurrences (by matching)
% of Subterm are replaced by Subterm1.
% Test: ?- substitute( b, f(a,b,c), e, F).
% Test: ?- substitute( b, f(a,X,c), e, F).
% Test: ?- substitute( b, f(a,X,Y), e, F).
% Test: ?- substitute( a+b, f( a, A+B), v, F).
% Test: ?- substitute(b,B,e,F).
% Test: ?- substitute(b,b,e,F).
% Test: ?- substitute(b,a,e,F).

% Logic, there are three cases:
% If Subterm = Term then Term1 = Subterm1
% otherwise if Term is 'atomic' (not a structure)
%   then Term1 = Term (nothing to be substituted)
%   otherwise the substitution is to be carried
%     out on the arguments of Term.

/* Case 1: SubTerm = Term --> SubTerm1 = Term1 */
substitute(Term, Term, Term1, Term1)  :-  !.

% Case 2: Se Term è atomico non c'è niente da sostituire
substitute( _, Term, _, Term)  :- atomic(Term), !.

/* Case 3: 
substitute(Sub, Term, Sub1, Term1)  :-
   Term  =..  [F|Args],                    % Term è composto da: F è il FUNTORE PRINCIPALE ed Args è la lista dei suoi argomenti
   substlist(Sub, Args, Sub1, Args1),      % Sostituisce Sub1 al posto di Sub nella lista degli argomenti Args generando Args1
   Term1  =..  [F|Args1].                  % Term1 è dato dal FUNTORE PRINCIPALE F e dalla nuova lista degli argomenti Args1

/* sublist: sostituisce all'interno della lista degli argomenti: */


substlist(_, [], _, []).


substlist(Sub, [Term|Terms], Sub1, [Term1|Terms1])  :-

    /* L'elemento in testa Term1 corrisponde all'eventuale sostituzione */
    substitute(Sub, Term, Sub1, Term1),

    /* Il problema è già risolto per le sottoliste e Terms1 rappresenta la sottolista Terms in cui tutte le occorrenze di Sub
       sono già state sostituite con Sub1:
    */
        substlist(Sub, Terms, Sub1, Terms1).
```

The first rule **rappresent** *represents* the particular case in which **SubTerm = Term** so the final **Term1=SubTerm1** (because I **substituite** *substitute* whole term)

The second rule **rappresent** *represents* the particular case in which **Term is an atom** so, regardless of the values ​​of SubTerm and SubTerm1, I do not perform any substitution

I think that up to here it is simple and my reasoning it is correct...next to it begin the more difficult part and I am not so sure...

The rule:

```
substitute(Sub, Term, Sub1, Term1)  :-
   Term  =..  [F|Args],                    
   substlist(Sub, Args, Sub1, Args1),      
   Term1  =..  [F|Args1].
```

**rappresent** *represents* a generic case in which I have an expression **rappresented** *represented* by **Term**, its possible subexpression **rappresented** *represented* by Sub, a new subexpression **Sub1** that eventually should be substituted when you meet an occurrence of **Sub** and the expression **Term1** that rappresent Term expression in which all the occurrences of SubTerm are substituited by SubTerm1.

So I can read it declaratively in this **whay** *way*:

**It is TRUE that Term1 rappresent *represents* Term expression in which all the occurrences of SubTerm are substituited by SubTerm1 if there are TRUE the following facts**:

1) The original expression **Term** can be decomposed in a list that have in the head its **main functor F** (the first operator executed in the expression evalutation) and later a sublist **Args** that rappresent the **arguments of this functor F** (I think that, in some case, Args can contain also other functor that, in this computational step, don't are the main functor...so in these case there are still some subproblem to solve)

2) It is true that substlist(Sub, Args, Sub1, Args1) that means that this is true that Args1 rappresent Args in which all the argument equals to Sub subexpression are replaced by Sub1 subexpression.

3) Finally it must be true that the new **Term1** is the result of the univ **=..** predicate beetwen the main functor F and the new arguments list **Args1** (I think that =.. recombine  the main functor F with the new arguments list

To perfrom the substitution in the arguments list it is used the **substlist** relation that it is divided into:

A BASE CASE:

```
substlist(_, [], _, []).
```

that simply say: if there is nothing in the arguments list, there is nothing to replace

A GENERAL CASE:

```
substlist(Sub, [Term|Terms], Sub1, [Term1|Terms1])  :-

    /* L'elemento in testa Term1 corrisponde all'eventuale sostituzione */
    substitute(Sub, Term, Sub1, Term1),

    /* Il problema è già risolto per le sottoliste e Terms1 rappresenta la sottolista Terms in cui tutte le occorrenze di Sub
       sono già state sostituite con Sub1:
    */
        substlist(Sub, Terms, Sub1, Terms1).
```

And this is the more difficult part to understand for me, I see it in the following way, declarative reading:

**It is TRUE that [Term1|Terms1] rappresent the list of arguments [Term|Terms] in which all the Sub term are replaced by Sub1** if it is true that:

1) substitute(Sub, Term, Sub1, Term1): that means that it is TRUE that Term1 (the head of the new arguments list it is Term (the head of the old arguments list) in which if Term == Sub ---> Term1 == Sub1

2)substlist(Sub, Terms, Sub1, Terms1) that means all the subproblem are solved, I think that this is an important point because the argument list **Term** is the argument list of a current main functor F but can contain other sub functors inside it and each of these rappresent a subproblem that have to be solved befor perform the Sub-->Sub1 replacements in this step.

But I am not so sure about this last thing...

someone can help me to deeply understand it

Tnx

Andrea

Comment: Spell check: available on modern web-browsers, in office suits (MS-Office, OpenOffice/LibreOffice), or as a stand-alone command-line tool, for example `aspell`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me start by saying that it would be nice if you kept questions short and to the point. The whole idea of Stackoverflow is that questions and answers will be later useful to others, and writing good questions is a big part of this.

Moving on: All programming languages have some right to the claim that the actual source code of a program is the most clear, complete, and exhaustive explanation (to a human) of what the program does. Prolog *definitely* has a right to that claim. It takes a bit of getting used to, but soon a well-written predicate does tell more about the program logic than an often futile attempt to give a precise specification / definition in an inherently ambiguous natural language, be it English, Italian, or even German.

Now to your question...

What does `=../2` do? We may look [here](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=%28=..%29/2), but, in a few words, we have `f(a,b, ..., x)` on the left side, and `[f, a, b, ..., x]` on the right side of it.

Assuming recursion, lists, matching and unification don't need to be explained here, the program you have extensively studied, commented in Italian, and thoroughly explained to us in English, does one simple thing: all occurrences of *Subterm* in *Term* are substituted by *Subterm1* in *Term1*.

This is done:

- by directly replacing simple terms (atoms) by matching
- by breaking down complex terms (of the form `f(Args)`) into a list (using `=..`), and then applying the algorithm recursively on the simpler terms in that list (the elements of `Args`). Afterwords, the list is reassembled, using `=..` again.

So if you have a nested term, you still get:

```
?- substitute(x, f( g( h(x,y,z), h(k,l,m) ), g(x,z) ), q, T).
T = f(g(h(q, y, z), h(k, l, m)), g(q, z)) ;
false.
```

The only slight difficulty one might encounter here is that `substitute` and `substlist` are mutually recursive. If this is giving you that much difficulty, one thing you can try and do is to remove all comments from the predicate definitions, fit the whole program on the screen at once (or print it out), and look at it and think about it until it makes sense. It works!

Comment: ok, I've probably been too verbose...I have read, read and read again the code but I still have a doubt...when in the substlist relation call the substitute relation in this way: substitute(Sub, Term, Sub1, Term1)
The program is calling passing it Sub that is what what needs to be replaced (if it is present), Term (where search it), Sub1 (What will replace Sub) and Term1 that is the final result. My doubt is the following one: in this case Term it is the HEAD of a list, so it is a single element (it is right?) So it will bell call or the rule 1 or the rule 2 (related to substitute)

Comment: but never the rule 3 because Term it is a single element and not a list...is it right? or am I loosing something?

Comment: In case I understand your question: yes, _Term_ is the head of a list, but it can be a functor (so it could look something like `f(a,b,...,x)`). So it is to be expected that the third clause of `substitute/4` will be matched. Why don't you try to trace a query of the form `?- substitute(x, f(g(h(x,y,z),h(k,l,m)),g(x,y)), q, F).`

Comment: In other words, each application of `=..` turns the outermost functor into a list. The arguments of a functor can be functors themselves, if I understand the code you have shown.

Comment: mmm ok...maybe it begin to be more clear...so...if I have something like: g(f(a,b)) the Main Funcotor is g and the argments list it is [f(a,b)] that itself contains the functor f...so when the sublist relation is called when it call substitute relation...it is called on the head of the list, that in this case is f(a,b), and that is a functor followed by its arguments...so in this case it is called the third rule that in turn divided it into: it's main functori f and its arguments list [a,b]...I hope that now it is right...tnx so much for your time